# I get none for validation form Django

Tags: python, django

```
class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
class Meta:
    model = models.User
    fields = ["first_name", "last_name", "email"]

def clean_password1(self):
    password = self.cleaned_data.get("password")
    password1 = self.cleaned_data.get("password1")

    print(password, password1)

    if password != password1:
        raise forms.ValidationError("비밀번호가 일치하지 않습니다.")
    else:
        return password

def clean_email(self):
    email = self.cleaned_data.get("email")
    try:
        models.User.objects.get(username=email)
        raise forms.ValidationError("이미 가입된 이메일 입니다", code="existing_user")
    except models.User.DoesNotExist:
        return email

def save(self, commit):
    username = self.cleaned_data.get("email")
    password = self.cleaned_data.get("password")
    user = super().save(commit=False)
    user.username = username
    user.set_password(password)
    user.save()
```

Here is my code for validation
and whenever i print password,
I really dont understand why
password1 is printed properly and password is none
i get none can anybody explain to me why this happen?

Comment: Can you please share your template code?

Answer (score 0):

You need to indent properly.
Python is reading your code as own functions and class.
Statements that belong together must have the same indentation depth.

Comment: thank you but depth issue happened when i upload on stackoverflow